# I want to insert from a select statement using union ALL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to use union on a query while inserting records in a table. The insert is also having some hard coded values. Rest of the values are coming from the union.
eg..

```
INSERT INTO my_test_one (name, sirname, Dept)
VALUES
  ((select 'name1','sirname1', Dept FROM my_test_one_backup WHERE dept = 500 
    union all
    select 'name1','sirname1', Dept FROM my_test_one_backup WHERE dept = 501 ));
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO my_test_one (name, sirname, Dept) 
(select 'name1','sirname1', Dept 
   FROM my_test_one_backup 
  WHERE dept = 500      
UNION ALL
 select 'name1','sirname1', Dept 
   FROM my_test_one_backup 
  WHERE dept = 501 );
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: @Jaimie F: Parenthesis are not what made the difference here. It was removing the `values` keyword, which is only used when inserting static values, rather than values from a select statement.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need no `VALUES` here. (`INSERT INTO ... ( ... ) SELECT ...`)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use two insert instead of using a union all?

```
INSERT INTO my_test_one (name, sirname, Dept)
SELECT 'name1','sirname1', Dept FROM my_test_one_backup WHERE dept = 500;

INSERT INTO my_test_one (name, sirname, Dept)
SELECT 'name1','sirname1', Dept FROM my_test_one_backup WHERE dept = 501;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO my_test_one (name, sirname, Dept)
SELECT 'name1','sirname1', Dept FROM my_test_one_backup WHERE dept in (500,501);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

If the table doesn't exist you may use this:

```
SELECT 'name1' [name],'sirname1' [sirname], Dept INTO my_test_one FROM my_test_one_backup WHERE dept = 500 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'name1','sirname1', Dept FROM my_test_one_backup WHERE dept = 501
```

Otherwise use this:

```
INSERT INTO my_test_one (name, sirname, Dept)
SELECT 'name1','sirname1', Dept FROM my_test_one_backup WHERE dept in (500,501)
```

Comment: @Fred in the `into my_test_one`, you may test it :)

Comment: That will work if `my_test_one` doesn't exist. The OP, however, seems to want to insert into an existing table.